# Strange Spacing to the Right of Divs using Flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

There is additional spacing I find nowhere in my code.  Can anyone pinpoint what part of my CSS is causing this issue? I have combed through all the CSS but can find nothing that removes it or adds this extra padding.

See image:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikPMo.png

Comment: Show us your code.

Comment: [link](https://replit.com/@novelboy/OverjoyedSugaryPriority-1)

Answer (score -1):

It's much easier to get answers if you post a small snippet of code, or a link to a live preview (via codepen, etc) but from the picture, it looks like you haven't removed the [default browser styles](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_default_values.asp).

Add something like this maybe:

```
*, html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

or, import a [css reset stylesheet](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) - this will effect a lot more than you probably want though.